# Problems with text after adding Bootstrap to site

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

Currently I am creating a portfolio and want to add a image carousel to my site. Because I couldn't figure out any way to do this I decided I would add Bootstrap to my site. After adding the Bootstrap CDN to my website's head tag some of my text changes size and colors as well.

What is the issue here? The same thing happens when I add w3.css.
Here are the images before and after adding Bootstrap:

[image]

Here is my website's code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <link href="hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Josefin+Slab:100" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Portfolio</title>
  <style>
    * {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .back {
      background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/26hisjGhYBD3dNbfa/giphy.gif);
      background-size: cover;
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      z-index: 1;
    }



    .text {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      padding-top: 36vh;
      font-size: 9vh;
      z-index: 9999;
      color: #dadada;
      text-shadow: 6px 6px grey;
    }

    .pageone {
      font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
      ;

      letter-spacing: .75vh;
    }

    .scroll {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      padding-top: 27vh;
    }

    .pagetwo {
      height: 100vh;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      background-color: #181818;
    }

    .about {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;

      font-size: 75px;
    }

    #about {
      margin-top: 7vh;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'lato', arial, sans-serif;
      text-shadow: 2.4px 2.4px grey;
    }

    html {
      background-color: #181818;
    }

    .abouttext {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      margin-left: 5vh;
      margin-right: 5vh;
      margin-top: 5vh;
      font-size: 3vh;
    }

    .seperated {
      margin-top: 5vh;
    }

    .scroll2 {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      margin-top: 8vh;
    }

    .threeheader {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 50px;
    }

    .pagethree {
      font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      height: 150vh;
    }

    #portabout {
      font-size: 3vh;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }

    .work {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      font-size: 20px;
    }


    .css,
    .premiere,
    .ps {
      margin: 5vw;
      max-width: 100%;
      max-height: 20vh;
    }

    figcaption {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-end;
    }

    .embed {
      position: relative;
      padding-bottom: 56.25%;
      padding-top: 30px;
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .embed iframe,
    .embed object,
    .embed embed {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }

    iframe {
      box-shadow: 4px 4px 1px 1px grey;
    }

    .thanks {
      color: white;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
      padding-top: 5vh;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 2.5vw;
    }

    #subscribe {
      font-size: 1.5vw;
    }

    a {
      color: white;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-shadow: 2.4px 2.4px grey;
    }

    a:hover {
      color: white;
      text-shadow: 2.4px 2.4px blue;
    }

    .scroll3 {
      margin-top: 2vh;
    }

    #portfolioabout {
      margin-top: 7vh;
      color: white;
      font-family: 'lato', arial, sans-serif;
      text-shadow: 2.4px 2.4px grey;
    }

    .portheader {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;

      font-size: 5vh;
    }

    .portmore {
      color: white;
      text-align: center;

      font-size: 2.5vh;
    }



  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="pageone">
    <div class="back">
      <div class="text">
        <h1 class="animated fadeInDown front" data-wow-duration="2s" data-wow-delay="5s">1080</h1>
      </div>

      <div class="scroll animated fadeIn">
        <a href="#aboutpage">
        <img src="scrolldown.png" alt="" id="down" class="hvr-float" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="aboutpage"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="pagetwo">

    <div class="aboutme">
      <h1 class="wow fadeInUp about" id="about">About Me</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="abouttext wow fadeIn">
      <p>I run a YouTube channel in which I benchmark the performance of computer hardware. I've been uploading content to YouTube for upwards of one year, and have amassed over 80 thousand views in that time period. While I'm not managing my channel I design
        graphics for others and myself. I design product advertisements, avatars and banners for YouTube, websites, company logos, and more. I am acquainted with a wide variety of softwares such as: Adobe Photoshop, Adobe After Effects, Adobe Premiere
        Pro, Adobe Lightroom and, Unreal Engine 4. I am also assimilating myself with HTML and CSS.<br>
        <div class="workcontainer">
          <div class="work hvr-grow"><img src="ps.png" alt="" class="ps"><img src="premiere.png" alt="" class="premiere"><img src="css.png" alt="" class="css"> </div>
        </div>
        <div class="seperated wow fadeInUp">To see my latest YouTube video scroll down.</div>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll2 wow fadeIn">
      <a href="#portfolio">
        <img src="scrolldown.png" alt="" id="down2" class="hvr-float" /></a>

    </div>
    <h1 id="portfoliod"></h1>
  </div>

  <div class="pagethree" id="portfolio">
    <div class='embed'>
      <figure><iframe src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=UUNETYZQrE6PEAjB0Pax6c3Q' frameborder='0' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <figcaption>Test</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <div class="thanks">
      <h2>Thanks for watching!</h2>
      <p id="subscribe">To subscribe click <a href="#">here.</a><br>Scroll down to see some of my work.</p>
      <div class="scroll3 animated fadeIn">
        <a href="#realportfolio">
    <img src="scrolldown.png" alt="" id="down" class="hvr-float" /></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="pagethree" id="realportfolio">
      <div class="portheader wow fadeInUp">
      <h1 id="portfolioabout">Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="portmore wow fadeIn">
        <p>Below are various works of mine all created within the last year.</p>
      </div>


    </div>


  <script src="wow.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    new WOW().init();
  </script>

  <script>
    //Not made by me credit w3schools
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Add smooth scrolling to all links
      $("a").on('click', function(event) {

        // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
        if (this.hash !== "") {
          // Prevent default anchor click behavior
          event.preventDefault();

          // Store hash
          var hash = this.hash;

          // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
          // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top
          }, 800, function() {

            // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
            window.location.hash = hash;
          });
        } // End if
      });
    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add the code to stackoverflow, not a link to your code.

Comment: Bootstrap adds an enormous amount of styles to your site, most of which are related to the responsive grid. If you're looking just to add an image carousel, look for a simple JS slideshow plugin. Adding BS just for that is like... buying a smartphone just to send texts.